# Floating Point Adder - Optimization of comparator

Tags: verilog

I have written a verilog code for a basic Floating point adder. The algorithm includes a 63 bit comparator to get the sign of the result.

```
if (a[62:0]>b[62:0])
 sign_result = a[63];
else 
 sign_result = b[63];
```

Is there anyway to reduce the size of the comparator or any other method and still get the sign result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only optimise the logic you get if the code you have is doing more than you really need.  Then the trick is persuading the compiler to understand the bits you don't need so it can optimise them.

Instead of comparing `a` with `b`, can you compare the *answer* with `0` instead (which amounts to just looking at the sign bit)?

Answer (score 0):

Your comparator is essentially duplicating your addition operation, which must be signed, given your description. What format are your numbers in? They're presumably already signed, so why isn't your adder just giving the correct positive or negative result? Why do you need a comparator at all?